# Is there a logic in which we accept an answer without up-voting it?

Tags: discussion, voting, accepting

Is there a logic in which we accept an answer without up-voting it?

If there is no such a logic, then why didn't SE make the accept button automatically trigger one up vote?

It also does not make sense if SE allows us to accept an answer with an extra down vote. :-)

Comment: Apart from when someone is accepting their own answer (in which case they can't upvote), I can't really think of a situation where an accept without an upvote makes sense. However, I think it's good to keep voting and accepting separate: Accepting without upvoting is mostly done by new users who haven't understood the voting/acceptance system. If their acceptance of an answer would automatically trigger an upvote, chances are that they're not going to understand that the two are separate processes. Maybe instead of an automatic vote, a popup could be displayed pointing to the voting FAQ.

Comment: @Jake: Thank you for the comment. Programmatically SE developers can prevent users who accept their own answers from upvoting the answers.

Comment: Sometimes there is an answer that works, so I feel I have to accept it, but I don't *like* it. Usually a better one will arrive eventually, which I can switch an accept too, but I can see why they don't merge the two.

Comment: One needs 15 rep to vote but there is no restriction on accepting.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think it makes sense to separate them even though they overlap in many cases.

Quoted from [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117910/163868):

> An answer may indeed solve or help you solve your original problem,
>   but it might not be an otherwise "good" answer. The accepting and
>   up-voting are different actions which mean different things.

There are however ways to improve.

- Way may want to get better at educating new users about the difference, e.g. refer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask which can be linked in comments by simply entering `[faq#howtoask]`.
- The interface could help telling the difference better.
- It would be helpful to be able [to search for answers that are accepted but not upvoted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/117897/163868).

Answer (score 15):

If I'm ever to get an Unsung Hero badge it needs lots of zero score accepted answers.

Comment: I don't think we're likely to ever see one of these awarded here on tex.sx. They're more for sites like [su], where you have a lot more one-time users popping in, asking and answering questions mediocrely.

Comment: Are you asking us to go through and downvote your answers?  (Does Unsung Hero work that way, or would that be a Singing but out-of-tune Hero?-)